# How can I generate a array with apache thrift

Tags: java, thrift

I need to generate a java array with apache thrift idl. Can someone tell me how can I do that thing?

I have tride it with List.

here the code

```
struct subscription{
1:list<string> control_data
2:string callback_url
3:bool post_notification
}
```

Can I do the same thing with an array as It's difficult to deal with a list in my project.

Comment: What did you try? And what are you trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: I have updated the question. I think now you can have an idea what I should do.

Answer (score 3):

There are only `list<T>`, `set<T>` and `map<K,V>`. What code is generated from that IDL depends on the language. For binary data like `byte[]` it is recommended to use the `binary` type instead.

Regarding your particular problem: If it is difficult with `list<>`, consider converting the data into an array temporarily, while dealing with them in your application logic.